# Correct syntax for like in access vba if then statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to figure out correct syntax for the following line.

```
If Me.Forms Like "5500*" Or "990*" Then
```

As is I get Run time 13 error. type mismatch

Forms is a text field and I am trying to check the value of the field in a form that if it is like 5500* or 990* to then do something.

I can't figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

VBA won't let you say "If *something* like *this* or *that*".  Instead you must repeat *something* and *like* for each of the comparisons: "If *something* like *this* or something like *that*".

So try it this way:

```vb
If Me.Forms Like "5500*" Or Me.Forms Like "990*" Then
```

However, `Forms` is also the name of a VBA collection.  So if Access still complains with the change I suggested, next I suggest you rename that `Forms` text box to something else.